# Compiling Haskell programs in Windows: is it possible without downloading something such as Cygwin?

Tags: haskell, cygwin

I am reading "Learn you a Haskell for great good", and have reached the chapter on I/O actions. I am using Windows, and have downloaded GHCi and WinGHCi.

I'm trying to compile a simple program and have saved a file on emacs as `helloworld.hs` with `main = putStrLn "hello, world"` in it.

The book says

> Open your terminal, navigate to the directory where `helloworld.hs` is located, and enter the following:
>
> ```
> $ ghc --make helloworld
> ```

However, if I enter `$ ghc --make helloworld` onto GHCi and WinGHCi I receive errors such as the one below, perhaps because I need to enter `$ ghc --make helloworld` elsewhere:

```
<interactive>:7:1: error:
    parse error on input ‘$’
    Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

In fact, in the online edition of the book (here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output), the author remarks that:

> For the purposes of this chapter, I'm going to assume you're using a unix-y environment for learning Haskell. If you're in Windows, I'd suggest you download Cygwin, which is a Linux-like environment for Windows, A.K.A. just what you need.

***Question 1***: Is it necessary for me to download Cygwin, or some other such thing, in order to be able to compile the program by entering `$ ghc --make helloworld`?

I ask this, since if there were some other way of compiling the program it would be very useful to know, since I am on a university computer and cannot download things like Cygwin without permission. (and even with permission it might not be possible, depending on what Cygwin requires)

***Question 2***: Given that only the technicians of my university are away for Easter, and only they can download things on this computer, how can I proceed with the chapter in I/O actions? Is it possible just to continue, but ignore the sections involving compiling programs?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to install [the Haskell platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/). It includes everything needed, and has no dependency. In particular it includes `stack`, an unavoidable tool for Haskell IMHO.

Comment: This is going to sound crazy, but how do I determine whether it has been downloaded onto the computer? The university technicians did it (We are not allowed to download things on university computers)

Comment: However you say you have downloaded GHCi. So I don't understand what you say. You mean GHCi has been downloaded by the technicians ?

Comment: Yes, it was not downloaded by me (It cannot be downloaded by me, but only by them). I've been using winGHCi and GHC for a few weeks, and never needed to go to the command line.

Comment: Ok, so maybe they have installed `stack` as well. Type `stack --version` in a terminal to check.

Comment: I typed `stack --version` into the command line of the Windows computer and I received `'stack' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` So is this proof that the technicians didn't download the whole Haskell Platform? I didn't even know you could download just winGHCi and GHCi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167813/discussion-between-user65526-and-stephane-laurent).

Comment: Yes, `stack` is included in the Haskell platform so they have not downloaded it *or* they choosed not to install `stack` during the installation (it's  optional). Sad. Note that you can install Haskell platform in "portable mode", so you can put it on a USB key I think.

Comment: As stack was mentioned, I'd say it alone is enough. It can download needd stuff itself, and, by my opinion it is the preferable way to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going to be stackless until the technicians come back after the Easter holiday!

Comment: Stéphane Laurent suggested downloading the whole Haskell Platform onto a windows computer, and then putting it on a USB and using Haskell in this way. Perhaps this might solve my problem

Comment: You don't really need Haskell platform while learning the basics. GHC and GHCi are enough.

Comment: Ok, so would you suggest that in the chapter on I/O actions in the book "Lear you a Haskell for a great good", I just ignore all the bits that require compiling, and keep going on? When will it be really necessary to be able to compile haskell files, in the way I currently can't?

Comment: Sorry for insisting on this point, but do you *literally* mean you aren't allowed to *download* files (which sounds a bit extreme -- aren't you allowed to, say, download a PDF file from the internet), or is the restriction that you can't *install* software?

Comment: You can do everything from ghci and ignore compiling (except perhaps in some advanced cases well beyond the LYAH book). But it isn't clear why you want to. If you have tried to compile something and got an error, just ask about it.

Comment: ad duplode's comment: I am allowed to download pdfs, but not install things like the Haskell Platform. To do that I require an administrator account and password.

Comment: ad n.m's comment: compiling is used in chapter 8. the first simple example is discussed there: http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Answer (score 4):

In many Unix and Linux shells (at least in Bash with which I'm most familiar) the default prompt is `$`. That's what the shell displays.

On Windows, when you open a Command Prompt, you'll typically see something like this instead:

```
C:\Users\mark>
```

(That's my prompt.)

While instructions often include the `$` prompt in order to indicate that the code is something that you're expected to enter at a command prompt, you're not expected to type the `$`. Just type `ghc --make helloworld` and hit *Enter*.

Also, you're not expected to do this from within GHCi, but from the command line. `ghc` is a command-line executable (an `.exe`), just like e.g. `git`. It has to be in your `path`, though, or otherwise, you'll have to type the full path the executable every time you want to run it.

Comment: When I put in `ghc --make helloworld` and hit Enter this comes up:   `ghc: unrecognised flag: -- did you mean one of: -D  -F -H Usage: For basic infomration, try the '--help' option`

Comment: @user65526 That's a different question :) You may have more luck adding a new question, because off the top of my head, I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded ghc**i**, which is interpreter. It is, by my opinion, totally enough to learn with it (it can `:load` sources as well), but you need to run a bit other commands. I don't know if your installation include compiler, I would not assume anything about it.

btw, you are typing command inside the interpreter already, the error message is specific for that

ps: to do same as "ghc --make" from the interpreter, run:

```
:load <file>
```

Yes, it will recurse to depenzecies automatically. You could use :help to learn other commands

Comment: How can I determine whether the whole Haskell Platform has been downloaded onto the computer (I did not download it, the technicians at my university did)?

Comment: sorry, I don't know. I would say if you have not downloaded it from https://www.haskell.org/platform/#windows  and installed then probably you don't have it.

Comment: I discovered I don't have `stack`, by entering `stack --version` into the command line, which resulted in `'stack' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. So the technicians of my university who installed winGHCi and GHCi on the computer did not install the full Haskell Platform.

Comment: it is a must for production use, but as I said for learning ghci should be enough

Comment: I chose the strategy of just `:l helloworld` and forgetting about trying to compile as suggested in the book. I'm hoping it won't matter for the purposes of getting through the next chapter or so.