# Compiling simple programs on Haskell on Windows using the command line

Tags: haskell

This is a follow-up to this question, which is about whether it is possible to compile simple programs on Haskell in Windows, without recourse to Cygwin: [Compiling Haskell programs in Windows: is it possible without downloading something such as Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554792/compiling-haskell-programs-in-windows-is-it-possible-without-downloading-someth/49555201#49555201)

For background, I asked this question, since if there were some other way of compiling the program it would be very useful to know, since I am on a university computer and cannot download things like Cygwin without permission. (and even with permission it might not be possible, depending on what Cygwin requires)

Someone responded to my question, suggesting I open the command line and put `ghc --make helloworld` and hit Enter. However, when I put in `ghc --make helloworld` and hit Enter this comes up:

```
ghc: unrecognised flag: -- 
did you mean one of: 
-D  
-F 
-H 
Usage: For basic infomration, try the '--help' option
```

The person answering the question suggested I made another question, asking why I received the above message. How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: I can reproduce your error if I type `ghc -- make helloworld` (note the extra space after the `--`) instead of `ghc --make helloworld` (which is how it should be written).

Comment: I get `target 'helloworld' is not a module name or a source file, if I write that in.

Comment: What is the name of the file with your code? I suspect it is `helloworld.hs`, rather than `helloworld`.

Comment: Yes, it is `helloworld.hs`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to use Windows to compile Haskell programs. In fact, I use Windows for all my Haskell programming! To compile a Haskell program, use `ghc --make <program>`; for instance, here it would be `ghc --make helloworld.hs`. Note that there is no space between `--` and `make`; including this space gives the error you describe. After running this command, an executable `helloworld.exe` file is produced.

Comment: It works on my computer - what happens when you try it?

Comment: @bradm I receive this message: `<no location info>: error : can't find file: helloworld.hs`

Comment: I get that message when I run ghc in a directory which does not contain `helloworld.hs`. Have you misspelt the name?

Comment: @bradm no: the file is `helloworld.hs`

Comment: @bradm I haven't misspelt it